# How to add a classname that is only present during development?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to add a classname that is only present during development.

Something like this:

```
 <body className={`${ devMode ? 'debug-screens' : '' }`}>
```

I'm hosting my project on Vercel, how can I know when my project is running on localhost or it's deployed?

Comment: You could check `window.location.href`?

Comment: @tadman I could but my project is using SSR and I'll have to dynamic import to be able to use 'window'.

Comment: It was a thought. The URL itself can be a big hint as to where you're running it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to detect the current environment:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
if(env === "development"){
  // do something
}
else if (env === "production"){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: Yup, this should work as long as OP's environment has `process.env` available.